# Find the locus of the middle points of the chords of the hyperbola $3x^2-2y^2+4x-6y=0$ parallel to the line $y=2x$ .

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, locus

> Find the locus of the middle points of the chords of the hyperbola $3x^2-2y^2+4x-6y=0$ parallel to the line $y=2x$ .

Equation of the chords of the hyperbola bisected at $(h,k)$ is given by $S_1=T$ where $S_1=3xx_1-2yy_1+2(x+x_1)-3(y+y_1)=3x_1^2-2y_1^2+4x_1-6y_1$

where I have chosen $(x_1,y_1)$ to be any point of the line $y=2x$

But the answer is not coming.Is there any fault in my answer.

Please help.

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101229224356AA8r5rs

Comment: In any conic, the midpoints of parallel chords are collinear and they lie on a line which goes through the center of the conic. So your problem boils down to finding the center of the hyperbola and the midpoint of a single chord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=2x+k$ be an equation of the chord and $(p,q)$ be a point on our locus.

Thus, for the $x$-coordinate of an intersect point we obtain:
$$3x^2-2(2x+k)^2+4x-6(2x+k)=0$$ or
$$5x^2+8(1+k)x+2k^2+6k=0,$$
which gives $$x_1+x_2=\frac{-8(1+k)}{5}$$ and
$$p=\frac{-4(1+k)}{5}$$ and $$q=2p+k=\frac{-8(1+k)}{5}+k=\frac{-3k-8}{5}.$$
Id est, $$k=\frac{5p+4}{-4}=\frac{5q+8}{-3},$$
which gives $$q=\frac{3}{4}p-1$$ and we got an equation of the locus:
$$y=\frac{3}{4}x-1.$$